# I don't get any kind of answer from dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a problem with aws DynamoDB. I'm trying to run the next query:

```
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  const params = {
    TableName: TABLE,
    Item: {
      CupsAndYear: CUP
    }
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docClient.get(params, function(error, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('[*] Error', error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log('[*] Success', response);
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

As you can see it is a really simple query. What I'm looking for is to get the item which key has the value of CUP. The problem is that, when I run this code inside a lambda, I'm not getting any kind of answer. I'm not getting any data and I'm not getting any error... simply nothing.

I've added two console.log inside the promise to see if I could get more clues about where is the problem but the lambda ends without any log... which is more strange.

I don't think it is a permission problem because the rol of the lambda has a full access on Dynamo DB. Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run inside a VPC?

Comment: If the Lambda isn't logging anything then it might be something to do with the handler not actually calling this function, or something of that sort...try put console.logs in the index and see where exactly it gets to

Comment: Not the lambda is not inside a VPC. The lambda is logging the console logs outside the promise. The console logs that are not logging are the ones inside the promise

Comment: OK, with a DynamoDB in local it works so the problem should be in the lambda configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try using the promise function directly instead of trying to use callbacks and wrap them in promises manually.

Something like:

```
response = await docClient.get(params).promise();
console.log('[*] Success', response);
```

or:

```
docClient.get(params).promise().then(function(response) {
   console.log('[*] Success', response);
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log('[*] Error', error);
});
```

Comment: Nop.. it doesn't work. Anyway. the code works with a DynamoDB in my local so the problem should not be in the code but in the lambda configuration

Comment: Curious if you are getting same behavior or some sort of other error

Comment: Nop I'm always getting the same behavior. take a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vcT7prdHI-q0rjwSk5B89zTINvkFP4dB/view?usp=sharing. It's not that I'm getting am error message... simply I'm not getting anything. No error or success message

Comment: Remove the return statement.  For this test, just exclude a return altogether.